# UITableViewCell's contents' alpha changes on its own

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I've got a simple `ViewController` -- let's call it SettingsViewController -- which contains a `UITableView` with some custom cells containing a `UILabel`.

Whenever I load said SettingsViewController the `UILabel` inside the 1st cell gets its alpha set to some small number on its own, I don't ever change the value of any alphas. Also, the highlighting works as expected on pressing the cells. Sometimes, when I return to SettingsViewController from a different one, it's a different random cell, possibly 2 or 3 cells.

Here's a gif of what happens when I first load the SettingsViewController:

[image]

I'm using Swift 2.0 with Xcode 7.0.1 and running this code on iOS 8.4.1 as well as 9. I've also seen this happen in a `UICollectionView` with cells containing only a `UIImageView` - in that case it was the `UIImageView` whose alpha would get changed.

Here's my code for the SettingsViewController:

```
class SettingsViewController: BronzeBaseViewController {

    @IBOutlet var settingsTable: UITableView!

    private let textCellIdentifier = "Cell"
    private let settingsList = ["Account Details", "About this App", "Terms of Service", "Privacy Policy"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.settingsTable.delegate = self
        self.settingsTable.dataSource = self
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource methods

extension SettingsViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsTableViewCell
        let row = indexPath.row

        cell.titleLabel.text = self.settingsList[row]
        cell.titleLabel.tag = row
        cell.backgroundColor = getBackgroundColor()

        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.settingsList.count
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate methods

extension SettingsViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        switch(indexPath.row) {
        case 0 :
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("accountDetailsSegue", sender: self)
        case 1:
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("legalViewSegue", sender: self)
        case 2:
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("legalViewSegue", sender: self)
        case 3:
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("legalViewSegue", sender: self)
        default:
        }

        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

And here's the class I'm using for the actual cells:

```
class SettingsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        super.awakeFromNib()

        let titleFont = UIFont(name: "ProximaNovaSoft-Regular", size: self.titleLabel.font.pointSize)
        self.titleLabel.font = titleFont
    }
}
```

Any idea what might be causing this and how to fix it properly?

Comment: is that just came to normal after few seconds ? I see there is some on and off thing going on there

Comment: are you using storyboard ?

Comment: settingsTableView iboutlet should be weak

Comment: The gif is looped. Basically, the font in the Labels everywhere should be black but when I load the ViewController, on the first one it becomes grayish - due to alpha being changed by something.

Comment: @Mr.T Yes, I am. Do you need any specifics from it?

Comment: also the label should be weak in your tableviewcell

Comment: how it turn to black again ? after you swipe the cells ?

Comment: It doesn't turn to black on its own normally - this is just the gif being looped. Some of them might turn grey or black when I go to another ViewController and then get back to this one.

Comment: Try setting your IBOutlets weak on your classes. This might will not solve the issue, and maybe BronzeBaseViewController does something odd.

Comment: @dirtydanee Thanks for the suggestions, I tried setting IBOutlets to weak but it didn't make a difference. Also, BronzeBaseViewController doesn't change any alpha or colours.

Comment: what is happening in getBackgroundColor() function?

Comment: it seems to me like a selection action would happen, not an alpha value change.

Comment: @dirtydanee getBackgroundColor() returns the following string: "#efefef". Also, why would a selection action happen if no cell is pressed? I checked in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and the alpha of the affected cells is 0.1 for some reason.

Comment: I created a project and used your classes but everything works fine. Does BronzeBaseViewController contain anything which may influence the views?

Comment: @Aigai0s No, it doesn't - I checked that twice now ;/

Comment: can you record a video? that would help. also change getBackgroundColor() to return a different color like red. and see if that changes the color of the label. #efefef is that gray that is currently showing.